# What is the best definition of MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

I have been using the Zend Framework with an MVC configuration, read about Ruby on Rails and I plan to explore other MVC frameworks in Python (Django?). I really like the way it isolates some parts of the logic, security, and validation. But after just one year of using it I read an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve#423847) saying that almost everyone has a wrong definition of MVC and that made me wonder:  What is the Right definition of MVC and where could I read about the pattern and  standard implementations?

**Update:** I understand we all know the BASIC definition (there's a model a controller and a view, the actions on the controller go to the view with some info after making something with the model) but I would love to know what is the definition you THINK everyone KNOWS and why is it wrong (and maybe that will explain to everyone where there could be mistakes, opinions, and of course what is your real point of view of this)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See Chapter 14 of the book: Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture, by Martin Fowler.

The section on MVC starts with:

> "Model View Controller (MVC) is one of
>   the most quoted (and most misquoted)
>   patterns around. It started as a
>   framework developed by Trygve
>   Reenskaug for the Smalltalk platform
>   in the late 1970s. Since then it has
>   played an influential role in most UI
>   frameworks and in the thinking about
>   UI design."

It also says:

> "As I think about MVC I see two
>   principal separations: separating the
>   presentation from the model and
>   separating the controller from the
>   view.
>
> ...
>
> Of these the separation of
>   presentation and model is one of the
>   most important design principles in
>   software, and the only time you
>   shouldn't follow it is in very simple
>   systems where the model has no real
>   behavior in it anyway. As soon as you
>   get some nonvisual logic you should
>   apply the separation. Unfortunately, a
>   lot of UI frameworks make it
>   difficult, and those that don't are
>   often taught without a separation.
>
> The separation of view and controller
>   is less important, so I'd only
>   recommend doing it when it is really
>   helpful. For rich-client systems, that
>   ends up being hardly ever, although
>   it's common in Web front ends where
>   the controller is separated out. Most
>   of the patterns on Web design here are
>   based on that principle."

Answer (score 20):

The most major mistake I find with peoples understanding of MVC is that they think the pattern encompasses more than it does. More specifically people often think:

- Model = DataBase
- View = HTML
- Controller = Business Logic and everything else.

This is often the way things work in a smaller application but reality MVC is a way to seperate the Business code from the presentation code. The Model does all the real business work. The views provide the look and feel, and the controller maps one to the other.

Comment: I didnt vote up because thats im not sure the model should be doing the real business work, i think the controller can do more than mapping(thats the router's job).

Answer (score 3):

I trust the MVC definition given [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) by Martin Fowler. However, you may want to notice the fact that more or less these framework have their own tweak in it. For example a framework like Django is more Model-Template-Controller due to its templating feature.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the same thing. As far as I am concerned anything that manages to separate the concerns of the display, the data/business objects and the control of those (initialisation, responding to user input) gets the benefit that MVC seeks to provide.

The aim is to move these items into re-useable components and be able to swap different implementations in and out and also be able to test the individual pieces in isolation. IMO that's what MVC is all about.

[This](http://ctrl-shift-b.blogspot.com/2007/08/interactive-application-architecture.html) is a pretty good write up of some of the history and popular implementations of the MVC paradigm. We should add the [Model - View - ViewModel](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/07/23/676272.aspx) pattern that is recommended for WPF in there too.

Answer (score 2):

The model-view-controller pattern proposes three main components or objects to be used in software development:

- A Model , which represents the underlying, logical structure of data in a software application and the high-level class associated with it. This object model does not contain any information about the user interface.
- A View , which is a collection of classes representing the elements in the user interface (all of the things the user can see and respond to on the screen, such as buttons, display boxes, and so forth)
- A Controller , which represents the classes connecting the model and the view, and is used to communicate between classes in the model and view.

Answer (score 1):

MVC is one of three ASP.NET programming models. MVC is a framework for building web applications using a MVC (Model View Controller) design: The Model represents the application core (for instance a list of database records). The View displays the data (the database records).

Answer (score 1):

The project is divided into three parts:

1. model: represented into database.
2. view: represented into your project’s interface that you could do it using html, javaScript and css.
3. controller: this is your business logic represented into your functions and it is consider the link between the model and view that represent level of security, too.