# Isn't Controller and Model is the same in php MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am learning PHP programming and came across MVC (Model View and Controller). Can anyone explain more about Model and Controller?

In the following stack overflow question [What is the best definition of MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425197/what-is-the-best-definition-of-mvc), there was an answer that Model is responsible for databases. But isn't it controller which process and use database?

Comment: Controller is your real-estate agent, models are the houses you're interested in and a view is the selective tour the agent will give you. The agent will gather a list of available houses and then prepare a view that will most flatter them. Obviously on these grounds no one can argue that a real estate agent and a house are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not the same. The Model contains everything your app can "do".

- Classes which describe your data structures? Part of the Model.
- Function/method/service for creating new users? Part of the Model.
- Sending email notification? Part of the Model.
- Complex database queries? Part of the Model.
- Everything else? Part of the Model.

What the Controller is is an "interface between your Model and the outside world." The Controller takes input from outside world, like an HTTP request, or a command line input, or an event on an event bus, and decides based on that input what action should be triggered in the Model and perhaps with what kind of View to respond. You may have different Controllers for different scenarios (web server, command line interface, cron job) which adapt those different scenarios to actions in the underlying Model.

Answer (score -1):

for MVC in PHP, i've found Codeigniter to be very useful! Altough it differs a little from MVC in other Languages...
here from theyr definition:

- The **Model** represents your data structures. Typically your model classes will contain functions that help you retrieve, insert, and update information in your database.
- The **View** is the information that is being presented to a user. A View will normally be a web page, but in CodeIgniter, a view can also be a page fragment like a header or footer. It can also be an RSS page, or any other type of “page”.
- The **Controller** serves as an intermediary between the Model, the View, and any other resources needed to process the HTTP request and generate a web page.

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: That's not MVC. What you written the description of CodeIgniter, that is being advertised as MVC ... which it is not.

Answer (score -2):

No, controller and model is not the same in MVC architecture. The model is being used to keep track of all the business data. **The controller tells it what to do, and the model knows how to do it**.

Controllers orchestrate the application. Controllers receive events from the
outside world (normally, user input), interact with the model, and display an
appropriate view to the user.

The model is responsible for maintaining the state of the application. A model is more than data; it enforces all the business rules that apply to
that data.

To learn how the concepts fit together, see the
following figure: [image]