# How to set data from an array as the values of form elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I am working on a product page, I enter the product using a form and save it to the Database. Now am trying to do EDIT. and would like when the Edit button is tapped. the user is navigated to the original input form only this time it will be pre-filled with the current product details, which can be edited in that same form and saved again.

when the edit button is tapped, an array of the product details is received from the database...and the user is also redirected to the right form. I now need some direction on how to insert this received Data into the form so it can be edited

```
$(document).on('click', '#edit_btn', function () {
    console.log('Edit button is working');
    const productId = $(this).parent().children('.product_id').attr('id');
    const product = getProductFromList(productId);

    console.log('selected product');
    console.log(product);
    //since products with variants  have no price attahced,
    if (product.price) {
        //Navigate to the product without variance page.
        window.location.href = 'index.php';
    } else {
        //Navigate to the product with variance page.
        window.location.href = 'pwv.php';
    }

});
```

html that creates the form

```
     <form method="POST" name="admin_form"
                                        action='https://baby-arcade debug.herokuapp.com/api/admin/products/create'
                                        id="admin_form" onsubmit="">
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                                                <!-- product_name_input -->
                                                <label for="inputProdcutName">Product Name</label>
<input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" id="inputproductname" placeholder="Enter Product Name">                                                <!--product_name_input-->
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                <!-- price input -->
                                                <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPrice">Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="inputPrice" placeholder="12000 (without comas)">
</div>                                                <!--price input-->
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <!-- start select shop -->
                                                <div id="Shops-container"></div>
                            <script id="ShopsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select shop</label>

                                <select class="form-control" name="shops" id="shops" required>

                                    {{#each this}}
                                    <option value="{{id}}"> {{name}} </option>
                                    {{/each}}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </script>                                                <!--endselect shop -->
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                                <!-- qty input -->
                                                <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPrice">Qty</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="qty" id="qty" placeholder="10">
</div>                                                <!-- qty input -->
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                                <!-- discount -->
                                                <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPrice">Discount</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="discount" id="inputDiscount" placeholder="10">
</div>                                                <!-- discount -->
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <!-- start select shop -->
                                                <div id="Shops-container"></div>
                            <script id="ShopsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select shop</label>

                                <select class="form-control" name="shops" id="shops" required>

                                    {{#each this}}
                                    <option value="{{id}}"> {{name}} </option>
                                    {{/each}}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </script>                                                <!--endselect shop -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                                <!-- desc input -->
                                                <label for="inputPassword4">Description</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"
    data-="this is a desc"></textarea>                                                <!--desc input -->
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <!-- start category select -->
                                                <div id="cats-container"></div>
                            <script id="catsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="fbc_label">Select one or multiple categories</label>


                                <select multiple="multiple" multiple class="form-control" name="category"
                                    id="product_category" required>
                                    <!-- <option value="0">Select category.</option> -->
                                    {{#each this}}
                                    <option value="{{id}}">{{name}}  </option>
                                    {{/each}}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </script>                                                <!-- end category select -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <!-- image select -->
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Upload image product</label>
                                                <input type="file" id="imageUrls" name="imageUrls"
                                                    accept="image/jpg"><br><br>
                                                <ul id="urlList">
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-2 pb-2 ml-2">
                                                        <div class="progress" id="progress">
                                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped"
                                                                role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="25"
                                                                aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="progress_bar">
                                                                <span class="progress_bar_Text">0%</span></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-12"><button type="button" onclick="handleImg()"
                                                            class="btn btn-primary3">Upload</button></div>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />

                                                </div>
                                                <!-- <p id="data"></p> -->
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <!-- radio buttons -->
                                                <div class="cntr">
    <label for="rdo-1" class="btn-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="rdo-1" name="big-item">
        <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="9"></circle>
            <path
                d="M10,7 C8.34314575,7 7,8.34314575 7,10 C7,11.6568542 8.34314575,13 10,13 C11.6568542,13 13,11.6568542 13,10 C13,8.34314575 11.6568542,7 10,7 Z"
                class="inner"></path>
            <path
                d="M10,1 L10,1 L10,1 C14.9705627,1 19,5.02943725 19,10 L19,10 L19,10 C19,14.9705627 14.9705627,19 10,19 L10,19 L10,19 C5.02943725,19 1,14.9705627 1,10 L1,10 L1,10 C1,5.02943725 5.02943725,1 10,1 L10,1 Z"
                class="outer"></path>
        </svg>
        <span>Small Item</span>
    </label>
    <label for="rdo-2" class="btn-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="rdo-2" name="big-item">
        <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="9"></circle>
            <path
                d="M10,7 C8.34314575,7 7,8.34314575 7,10 C7,11.6568542 8.34314575,13 10,13 C11.6568542,13 13,11.6568542 13,10 C13,8.34314575 11.6568542,7 10,7 Z"
                class="inner"></path>
            <path
                d="M10,1 L10,1 L10,1 C14.9705627,1 19,5.02943725 19,10 L19,10 L19,10 C19,14.9705627 14.9705627,19 10,19 L10,19 L10,19 C5.02943725,19 1,14.9705627 1,10 L1,10 L1,10 C1,5.02943725 5.02943725,1 10,1 L10,1 Z"
                class="outer"></path>
        </svg>
        <span>Big Item</span>
    </label>
</div>                                                <!-- end radio btns -->
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end image select -->
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary2 btn-lg">
                                            Save
                                        </button>
                                    </form>
```

[image: this is the console log of the data am trying to insert into the form so it can be editted]

Comment: Are there more details in how you're storing this data? It's hard to answer this question as is. One way is that you could request this data from your database when the product details page is loaded

Comment: this is an example of how am storing the data https://baby-arcade-debug.herokuapp.com/api/admin/products

Comment: yeah, need more info.  Are you looking for how to get the data in 'product' into index.php or pwv.php?  You could try query string or local storage if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: yes am looking at how to get the Data in 'Product' into a form in either index.php or pwv.php... am very new to Js so not quite sure on how to go about it

Comment: @Kyle how do i add those values into the form?

Comment: @DanielSmurts You can set values to the form using selectors that is class or id

Comment: @SumeshTG okay but how do i make it 'dynamic' so that the values added to the form are the current product being edited..ive added an image of the data am getting back from the server that i want to add to the form

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTML that creates your form? Do you use element `id` or `name` attributes to indicate which value belongs to which form item? Or do you have custom attributes?

Comment: @DanielSmurts use the same key in your json as element name, class, or id

Comment: @Marius i have edited the qn to add the html for the form

Answer (score 1):

You can use the example JS function below. This function can be expanded. Currently it wil only support values where the element value can be set with `value`.

```js
var data = {
  name: "prod1",
  price: 500
}

populateForm(data, "admin_form");

function populateForm(obj, formName) {
  var form = document.querySelector("form[name=\"" + formName + "\"]");

  for (var key in obj) {
    var inputs = form.querySelectorAll("[name=\"" + key + "\"]"); // You can use querySelector if you will be certain there is only one element with the same name and ignore the loop.
    
    if (inputs) {
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var input = inputs[i];
        //You will have to check the tagname and type of the input since some inputs set their values differently
        input.value = obj[key];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" name="admin_form" action='https://baby-arcade debug.herokuapp.com/api/admin/products/create' id="admin_form" onsubmit="">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <!-- product_name_input -->
      <label for="inputProdcutName">Product Name</label>
      <input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" id="inputproductname" placeholder="Enter Product Name">
      <!--product_name_input-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- price input -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPrice">Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="inputPrice" placeholder="12000 (without comas)">
      </div>
      <!--price input-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <!-- start select shop -->
      <div id="Shops-container"></div>
      <script id="ShopsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select shop</label>

          <select class="form-control" name="shops" id="shops" required>

            {{#each this}}
            <option value="{{id}}"> {{name}} </option>
            {{/each}}
          </select>
        </div>
      </script>
      <!--endselect shop -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <!-- qty input -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPrice">Qty</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="qty" id="qty" placeholder="10">
      </div>
      <!-- qty input -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <!-- discount -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPrice">Discount</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="discount" id="inputDiscount" placeholder="10">
      </div>
      <!-- discount -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <!-- start select shop -->
      <div id="Shops-container"></div>
      <script id="ShopsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select shop</label>

          <select class="form-control" name="shops" id="shops" required>

            {{#each this}}
            <option value="{{id}}"> {{name}} </option>
            {{/each}}
          </select>
        </div>
      </script>
      <!--endselect shop -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <!-- desc input -->
      <label for="inputPassword4">Description</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" data-="this is a desc"></textarea>
      <!--desc input -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <!-- start category select -->
      <div id="cats-container"></div>
      <script id="catsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="fbc_label">Select one or multiple categories</label>


          <select multiple="multiple" multiple class="form-control" name="category" id="product_category" required>
            <!-- <option value="0">Select category.</option> -->
            {{#each this}}
            <option value="{{id}}">{{name}} </option>
            {{/each}}
          </select>
        </div>
      </script>
      <!-- end category select -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <!-- image select -->
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Upload image product</label>
      <input type="file" id="imageUrls" name="imageUrls" accept="image/jpg"><br><br>
      <ul id="urlList">
      </ul>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-2 pb-2 ml-2">
          <div class="progress" id="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="progress_bar">
              <span class="progress_bar_Text">0%</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12"><button type="button" onclick="handleImg()" class="btn btn-primary3">Upload</button></div>
        <br />
        <br />

      </div>
      <!-- <p id="data"></p> -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <!-- radio buttons -->
      <div class="cntr">
        <label for="rdo-1" class="btn-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="rdo-1" name="big-item">
        <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="9"></circle>
            <path
                d="M10,7 C8.34314575,7 7,8.34314575 7,10 C7,11.6568542 8.34314575,13 10,13 C11.6568542,13 13,11.6568542 13,10 C13,8.34314575 11.6568542,7 10,7 Z"
                class="inner"></path>
            <path
                d="M10,1 L10,1 L10,1 C14.9705627,1 19,5.02943725 19,10 L19,10 L19,10 C19,14.9705627 14.9705627,19 10,19 L10,19 L10,19 C5.02943725,19 1,14.9705627 1,10 L1,10 L1,10 C1,5.02943725 5.02943725,1 10,1 L10,1 Z"
                class="outer"></path>
        </svg>
        <span>Small Item</span>
    </label>
        <label for="rdo-2" class="btn-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="rdo-2" name="big-item">
        <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="9"></circle>
            <path
                d="M10,7 C8.34314575,7 7,8.34314575 7,10 C7,11.6568542 8.34314575,13 10,13 C11.6568542,13 13,11.6568542 13,10 C13,8.34314575 11.6568542,7 10,7 Z"
                class="inner"></path>
            <path
                d="M10,1 L10,1 L10,1 C14.9705627,1 19,5.02943725 19,10 L19,10 L19,10 C19,14.9705627 14.9705627,19 10,19 L10,19 L10,19 C5.02943725,19 1,14.9705627 1,10 L1,10 L1,10 C1,5.02943725 5.02943725,1 10,1 L10,1 Z"
                class="outer"></path>
        </svg>
        <span>Big Item</span>
    </label>
      </div>
      <!-- end radio btns -->
    </div>
    <!-- end image select -->
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary2 btn-lg">
                                            Save
                                        </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, @Marius.. thank you, on its own, this works, but can't get it to work as a result of clicking the edit button on the all products page...the navigation on its own works, your code on it own works, how to connect them?

Answer (score 0):

Given you have an api endpoint `api/admin/products`

You would want to make a request when the user loads the Product Details page.

An example of such a request using just JS would be:

```
const http = new XMLHttpRequest()

http.open("GET", `${YOUR_API_ENDPOINT}`)
http.send()

http.onload = () => console.log(http.responseText)
```

Here's more details on how to use the [`XMLHttpRequest` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), there is also the newer [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) syntax (I haven't used this personally so I didn't want to give this as an answer).

Typically this is where some kind of library like AngularJS can make your life easier by handling your application's  [MVC (Model View Controller)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425197/what-is-the-best-definition-of-mvc), where you can define multiple page routes and then add logic to handle what data is passed into that page. Which will help you with handling things like waiting for the data to load, and then populating the data into the right places.

With your current implementation, you would probably add an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) that runs when `index.php` is loaded, and then it will fire that request to fetch the data.

Comment: I am already successfully fetching the data and even logging it in the console.. I don't know how to insert in the form in the correct form elements so as to enable the user to edit it